# Preventing ArrayIndexOutofBoundsException in Java

Tags: java, indexoutofboundsexception

How to prevent `ArrayIndexOutofBoundsException` in below code, while transforming data storing header and value for each record to prepare insert query afterwards.

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\files\\test.dat"));
HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> map = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>();
int lineNumber = 1;
String[] columnName = null;
ArrayList<String[]> value = null; // temp array
String line;
String[] arr;
List<String> headers = null;

while (reader.ready())
    if (!(line = reader.readLine()).isEmpty()) {
        arr = line.split("[\\r\\n]+");

        if (lineNumber == 1) {
            lineNumber++;
            continue;  
        }
        if (lineNumber == 2) {
            headers= Arrays.asList(arr[0].split("\\|"));
            value=new ArrayList<String[]>();
        }
        else
            value.add(arr[0].split("\\|"));// create values

        lineNumber++;
    }

// transform data
for (int i = 1; i < headers.size(); i++) {
    ArrayList<String> ar = new ArrayList<String>();

    for (int j = 0; j < value.size(); j++)
        ar.add(value.get(j)[i]); // <---- Getting error here

    map.put(headers.get(i), ar);
}

System.out.println(map);
```

}

`test.dat` has below data. At 4th record above code trying to retrieve after *Emp sal* but there is no data so the code fails.

```
"X"|"Y"|"12345 0000"

"Emp No"|"Emp sal"|"Emp Name"

1|23.4567|"jhon"

2|0.4567|"steve"

3|9.4567|"jhon"

4|123
```

Comment: On which line of code do you get the error?

Comment: Index out of bounds means there's a bug in your logic, where you're going past the end of the array. The exception will tell you exactly what line that's happening on. Figure out what you're doing wrong and fix it.

Comment: You can check the length of an array using the `length()` method, to ensure it is safe to access a given element. Then you need to decide how to handle missing data (e.g. skip that record, or exit, or print an error, or whatever)

Answer (score 2):

Do not assume, that given array or list always has some element at given position. Check the container's size first! You are expecting, that each line contains the same number of elements as the header line. So before calling `value.get(j)[i]` check that `value.get(j).length == headers.size()`. If not, you can `continue` or throw an exception.